# How to loop through checkbox value in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i have this problem regarding the checkbox of my gridview, upon checking the checkboxes all  checked rows should be reassigned where reassign button is clicked. But it is only reasigning the first items checked, it seems that it is not looping through the gridview. Can you please help me identify whats wrong or missing in my code:

```
  protected void Reassign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in ParticularWorkGridView.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox _checkBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ReassignCheckBox");
            Label _RecordNumberLabel = (Label)row.FindControl("NumberLabel");

            if (_checkBox != null &&
                _checkBox.Checked == true)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[Reassig]", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                string MemberID = DropDrownList.SelectedValue;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("number", _NumberLabel.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", MemberID);

                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
                Response.Redirect("ParticularWork.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
Response.Redirect("ReassignpParticularWork.aspx");
```

Outside the "is checked" condition.

You are moving away at the first checked and not keep iterating thru the rest xD

Comment: lol.. thanks Rockster.. i really did not see that.. its now working fine :)

Answer (score 2):

You should only be looping through datarows.

```
if (row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) { /* your code */ }
```

Look at the `DataControlRowType` enumeration to see the different types and it will make sense.

Also, I would highly recommend using `using` blocks with your ADO.NET classes (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`). This way, you don't need to call `.Close()` or `.Dispose()`; it will be handled automatically, and your code will look cleaner.

Comment: Dont have to worry if cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); thows an execption and and leaves connections open